# install separately bower components to directories

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, bower, bower-install

```
{
  ...
  "dependencies": {
      "bootstrap": "latest",
      "backbone": "latest"
  },
  "install": {
  "path": "src/libs",
  "sources": {
      "bootstrap": [
        "bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
        "bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",
        "bower_components/bootstrap/dist/fonts/*"
      ]
  }
}
```

I want to install bootstrap to `src/libs/bootstrap/css/`(css file), `src/libs/bootstrap/js/`(js file), `src/libs/bootstrap/fonts/`(asset file),
but except backbonejs

I also use bower-installer